# Injection Vulnerability Prevention

Tags: xss

I am getting error in Understand Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)

> There was an unhandled exception. Please reference ID: OODKFWIY.
> Error: Restforce::ErrorCode::InvalidType. Message: INVALID_TYPE:
> select id from cvcs__c where name = 'xbc1' and ^ ERROR at
> Row:1:Column:16 sObject type 'cvcs__c' is not supported. If you are
> attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after
> the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
> the appropriate names.

I am stuck in this solution Please give me fine solution.

Comment: Error doesn't seem to be complaining about XSS, is the object API name correct? Check if you have object level permission on the custom object, also FLS after that. At the moment it seems to be complaining about object level. How do you run the code to get this error?

Comment: Are you doing [this Trailhead sequence](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/secdev_inject_get_started_wappsec)? Did you follow the instructions and sign up for a specially-configured developer org, in the first unit? You can't run the challenges against a regular Playground.